# Replacing value in DbDataRecord c# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code on my page:

```
 private void populateNewTableRow(DbDataRecord rowData)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();


            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.ID = rowData.GetInt32(rowData.GetOrdinal("jobId")).ToString();
            radioButton.GroupName = "MaintenanceRecord";
            cell1.Controls.Add(radioButton);
            tr.Cells.Add(cell1);

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell2.Text = rowData.GetInt32(rowData.GetOrdinal("jobId")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell2);

            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            cell3.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("odometerReading")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell3);

            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            cell4.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("jobDescription")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell4);

            TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
            cell5.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("status")).ToString();// this
            tr.Cells.Add(cell5);



            tbl_MaitenanceRecord.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
```

my values for `this` in my database is only string "0" or "1", how can I replace the value 0 to "Pending" and value 1 for "Done" and pass it to its `cell.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Check the value from the database and return whatever you want in the cell based on that.

```
TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
            cell5.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("status")).ToString() == "0" ? "Pending" : "Done";
```